# How to initialize a class with a property that is constrained to a generic type and a protocol in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, class, generics, protocols

I am initializing my `Glide` class with a `UIViewController` that is conformed to a protocol `Glideable` like so:

```swift
class Glide : NSObject, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate, UIScrollViewDelegate {
    private var card: (Glideable & UIViewController)?
    init(parentViewController: UIViewController, configuration: GlideConfiguration, card: Glideable & UIViewController) {}
}
```

So when you create an instance of this class, you pass a `UIViewController` that is also conformed to a `Glideable` protocol. Now I want to change this a bit so that if you have a `UIViewController` wrapped inside a `UINavigationController` like so:

```swift
let navCardView = UINavigationController(rootViewController: CardViewController())
```

then I initialize my `Glide` class with `navCardView` which is no longer just a `UIViewController` but a `UINavigationController` but I also want to make sure that `CardViewController` is conforming to `Glideable` protocol.

Any help in implementing such architecture using Generics will be helpful. I can't seem to understand how I can make a generic type constrained to a protocol.

Any idea will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: It's not clear what "initialize my Glide class with navCardView" would mean here. `navCardView` doesn't conform to Glideable, so it cannot be assigned to `card` (and any code that worked on `card` wouldn't apply). Do you mean that you want to pass navCardView to Glide.init, and have Glide.init extract the first viewController from its stack, store that as `card` and then ignore the rest of the navCardView? Or do you mean that you want to conform UINavigationController to Glideable? Or do you mean something else? (If the latter, it matters what the protocol looks like.)

Comment: You can't change what existing init in `UINavigationController` expects. You could wrap `UINavigationController` instantiation inside the function that only accepts `Glideable`, or you could subclass `UINavigationController` to only work with `Glideable`... But it really depends how are you using it. So you need to share a bit more on what your endgame is.

Comment: BTW if `Glideable` is always used in conjunction with UIViewCOntroller, best way to describe it is on protocol level `protocol Glideable: UIViewController`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what exactly you are trying to do, but in general you should use an enum to represent heterogenous types in swift.  Here is how you can use a enum to handle the two cases, navigation controller and no navigation controller as well as make the class generic to a specific kind of view controller:

```
import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport
import Combine

protocol Glideable { }

typealias GlideableViewController = Glideable & UIViewController

final class Glide<SomeGlidableViewController: GlideableViewController>: NSObject, Glideable {
  private enum Wrapped {
    case viewController(SomeGlidableViewController), navigationContoller(UINavigationController, SomeGlidableViewController)
    var glideViewController: SomeGlidableViewController {
      switch self {
      case let .viewController(viewController): return viewController
      case let .navigationContoller(_, viewController): return viewController
      }
    }
    var navigationController: UINavigationController? {
      guard case let .navigationContoller(navigationContoller, _) = self else { return nil }
      return navigationContoller
    }
  }
  private let wrappedViewController: Wrapped
  init(glideableViewController: SomeGlidableViewController) {
    wrappedViewController = .viewController(glideableViewController)
    super.init()
    commonInit()
  }
  init?(navigationController: UINavigationController) {
    guard let glideableViewController = navigationController.topViewController as? SomeGlidableViewController else {
      return nil
    }
    wrappedViewController = .navigationContoller(navigationController, glideableViewController)
    super.init()
    commonInit()
  }
  private func commonInit() {
    print("This class wraps a VC of type: \(SomeGlidableViewController.self)")
    print("The wrapped VC is \(wrappedViewController.glideViewController)")
    if let navigationController = wrappedViewController.navigationController {
      print("It is wrapped in a navigation controller")
    } else {
      print("It is not wrapped in a navigation controller")
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! The code helped me clarify some of my concepts regarding such a situation and I am able to handle both cases now. Thanks a lot! :)